# watermark/border around image in Swift to be shared to Instagram Stories

Tags: swift, image

I have got this following function which works correctly when sharing an image to instagram stories

```
private func shareToInstagramStories() {
guard let imagePNGData = UIImage(data: imageData!)?.pngData() else { return }
guard let instagramStoryUrl = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share") else { return }
guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramStoryUrl) else { return }
let itemsToShare: [[String: Any]] = [["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage": imagePNGData]]
let pasteboardOptions: [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey: Any] = [.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)]
UIPasteboard.general.setItems(itemsToShare, options: pasteboardOptions)
UIApplication.shared.open(instagramStoryUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

what I would like to try and do is be able to put a border / watermark over the image with some branding. Is this possible to add this within the function above or would I call the the "watermark" function first then pass result to shareToInstagramStories function

thanks

Comment: How this relates to SwiftUI?

Comment: Guess its more of a generic Swift Question, apologies will edit to remove references to SwiftUI

Answer (score 1):

found out what worked for me:

```
func generateImageWithText() -> UIImage? {
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

        let btnDetail = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        btnDetail.setTitle("watermarkText", for: .normal)
        btnDetail.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 72)
        btnDetail.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 5
        btnDetail.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        btnDetail.contentVerticalAlignment = .top
        btnDetail.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
        btnDetail.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        btnDetail.autoresizesSubviews = true
        btnDetail.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(btnDetail.bounds.size, false, 0)
        imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        btnDetail.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return imageWithText
    }

    func shareToInstagramStories() {
        guard let imagePNGData = generateImageWithText()!.pngData() else { return }
          guard let instagramStoryUrl = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share") else { return }
          guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramStoryUrl) else { return }

          let itemsToShare: [[String: Any]] = [["com.instagram.sharedSticker.stickerImage": imagePNGData]]
          let pasteboardOptions: [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey: Any] = [.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)]
          UIPasteboard.general.setItems(itemsToShare, options: pasteboardOptions)
          UIApplication.shared.open(instagramStoryUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
      }
```

I used UIButton with isUserInteractionEnabled = false instead of UILabel as I wanted the text to have some vertical alignment.

hopefully this will help someone else out there